# Can't deploy marketing definitions, "definition manager is in read only mode"

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, marketing-definitions

I'm getting the error `The definition manager is in read only mode in this environment` when triggering "Deploy Marketing definitions" from control panel.

How do I enable "write mode?" on CM server? And how often are we supposed to deploy definitions? Shouldn't this happen automatically?

Config definition (from showconfig.aspx)

```xml
<goal definitionInterface="Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Goals.IGoalDefinition, Sitecore.Marketing">
<definitionManager type="Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Goals.GoalDefinitionManager, Sitecore.Marketing" singleInstance="true">
    <config>   
        <customTaxonomyFieldMappings patch:source="Sitecore.Marketing.config">                
            <mapping fieldId="{E7B5C821-A54C-4264-9C06-C6EBDBFCD6B8}" taxonomyRootId="{13D17E8A-FED4-4799-8DEF-05E9691A3E15}" />
            <mapping fieldId="{B3D6C41E-E37B-48AB-B8EC-13DCA18CE729}" taxonomyRootId="{7DE5CC49-D985-49E1-AC61-663A1411AE42}" />
            <mapping fieldId="{781346DF-7E91-42F1-BA62-A63572520850}" taxonomyRootId="{D7D814A0-294D-444C-BED0-EEAEA7CD5A27}" />
        </customTaxonomyFieldMappings>

        <knownTaxonomyFieldMappings patch:source="Sitecore.Marketing.config">            
            <mapping fieldId="{8B553339-088A-4CFA-AB21-B8D0B8C0B77D}" taxonomyRootId="{733CECC5-1A6D-4C81-8267-D52A80349EE4}" />
        </knownTaxonomyFieldMappings>
        <activationFeed patch:source="Sitecore.MarketingProcessingRole.config" />
    </config>
    <param desc="repository" ref="marketingDefinitions/goal/repositories/rdb" patch:source="Sitecore.Marketing.config" />
    <param desc="classificationResolver" type="Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefaultClassificationResolver, Sitecore.Marketing" patch:source="Sitecore.Marketing.config" />
    <param desc="definitionFieldLabelResolver" type="Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.ItemBasedDefinitionFieldLabelResolver, Sitecore.Marketing" patch:source="Sitecore.Marketing.config">
    <param desc="databaseName" ref="marketingDefinitions/itemRepositoriesDatabase" />
    </param>
    <param desc="searchProvider" patch:source="Sitecore.Marketing.config" ref="marketingDefinitions/goal/searchProviders/notSupported" />
    <param desc="isReadOnly" type="System.Boolean" factoryMethod="Parse" arg0="true" patch:source="Sitecore.Marketing.config" />
</definitionManager>
<repositories>
    <rdb type="Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.DefinitionData.Marketing.GoalDefinitionRdbRepository, Sitecore.Analytics" singleInstance="true">
        <param desc="connectionStringName">reporting</param>
        <param desc="cache" type="Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.DefinitionData.Marketing.RdbCache.DefinitionCache`1[[Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Goals.Data.GoalDefinitionRecord, Sitecore.Marketing]], Sitecore.Analytics">
        <param desc="name">marketing.rdb.goal</param>
        <param desc="maxSize">20MB</param>
        </param>
        <param desc="availableCulturesCache" type="Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.DefinitionData.Marketing.RdbCache.Cache`2[[Sitecore.Data.ID, Sitecore.Kernel],[System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]]]], Sitecore.Analytics">
        <param desc="name">marketing.rdb.goal.cultures</param>
        <param desc="maxSize">20MB</param>
        </param>
    </rdb>
    <item type="Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Goals.Data.ItemDb.GoalDefinitionItemRepository, Sitecore.Marketing" singleInstance="true" patch:source="Sitecore.Marketing.config">
        <param desc="databaseName" ref="marketingDefinitions/itemRepositoriesDatabase" />
        <param desc="assumeActive" type="System.Boolean" factoryMethod="Parse" arg0="false" />
    </item>
</repositories>
<searchProviders patch:source="Sitecore.Marketing.config">
    <notSupported type="Sitecore.Marketing.Search.NotSupportedSearchProvider`1[[Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Goals.IGoalDefinition, Sitecore.Marketing]], Sitecore.Marketing" />
</searchProviders>
</goal>
```

Full exception:

```cs
Message: An unhandled exception occurred.
Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass22.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1e()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<.cctor>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) 

Nested Exception Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more errors occurred.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.DefinitionData.Marketing.Deployment.DeploymentManager.DeployAll[TDefinitionInterface](CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Client.Applications.Marketing.Utilities.DeployMarketingDefinitions.DeployMarketingDefinitionsController.DeployDefinitionTypes(String[] definitionTypes)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Client.Applications.Marketing.Utilities.DeployMarketingDefinitions.DeployMarketingDefinitionsController.DeployDefinitions(String definitionTypes, Boolean publishTaxonomies)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
> Nested Exception
Exception: System.NotSupportedException
Message: The definition manager is in read only mode in this environment.
Source: Sitecore.Marketing
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefinitionManagerBase`1.EnsureWriteIsEnabled()
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefinitionManagerBase`1.Save[TRecord](TDefinition definition, Boolean activate, IDefinitionRepository`1 repository, Action`2 setCustomFields)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Goals.GoalDefinitionManager.SaveAsync(IGoalDefinition definition, Boolean activate)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.DefinitionData.Marketing.Deployment.DeploymentManager.<DeployAllAsync>d__d`1.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Could you find `GoalDefinitionManager` configuration in `/sitecore/admin/ShowConfig.aspx` and include it in your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Background

Under `sitecore/marketingDefinitions/goal/definitionManager`, you have the following parameter configured:

```
<param desc="isReadOnly" type="System.Boolean" factoryMethod="Parse" arg0="true" patch:source="Sitecore.Marketing.config" />
```

This means that the definition manager is configured to be read-only.

Here's the original text of this node in ***Sitecore.Marketing.config***:

```
<param desc="isReadOnly" type="System.Boolean" factoryMethod="Parse" arg0="$(marketingDefinitions.isReadOnly)" />
```

As you can see, the value of this parameter is taken from `marketingDefinitions.isReadOnly`—a Sitecore configuration variable. This variable is defined in the same file and by default it's set to false:

```
<sc.variable name="marketingDefinitions.isReadOnly" value="false" />
```

This variable can be set to true in certain environments. Here's a list of predefined configs where this value is changed to `true`:

- Sitecore.MarketingCD.config.disabled
- Sitecore.MarketingProcessingRole.config.disabled
- Sitecore.MarketingReportingRole.config.disabled
- Sitecore.Xdb.Remote.Server.config.disabled

### Solution

Make sure that the configuration of your CM server is correct. It shouldn't be configured as a processing or a CD server. The variable `marketingDefinitions.isReadOnly` needs to be set to `false`, the same as it is out of the box.

Comment: That was exactly the issue. In my case the setting was being overwritten by
`Sitecore.MarketingProcessingRole.config`